# Cloning an existing CarrierWave file to another Mongoid record

Tags: mongoid, carrierwave, copying, cloning

I have a Mongoid model called Product that has a `has_one` and `belongs_to` association to itself so I can have an `original` and `new_version` behaviour.

This is done so the Product can be modified in a new version without affecting the original version until this new version is approved. I manage to `dup` the original product including it's multiple CarrierWave attachments to create the `new_version` (this doesn't re-uploads the file as it already exists).

When I modify the new version and upload a different files and approve this new version, I need to assign these new files (and other attributes) to the original product. To do this I'm using block of code similar to this:

```
# self is this context is the new product version
original_product.assign_attributes self.attributes.except(*Product.attributes_to_exclude)
original_product.save && self.destroy
```

In the attributes I exclude, I exclude the `id, _id, created_at, updated_at` and others that are not relevant or necessary to copy to the original version. This works great for all the non CarrierWave file attributes, but the file attributes are not saved. I know that all that it's stored in the Mongoid document is the file name and I wish it could work as simple as just modifying this document's attribute.

Any ideas as of how I could achieve this? What I'm basically looking for is the same behaviour as the `dup` method but in the approval context I'm explaining.

Thanks!